# Django no such column error after migrating

Tags: python, django

Following some Django tutorials and getting a weird error I can not get my head around. I've migrated the database a few times previously, so before I start I delete all the files in the apps 'migrations' folder. Here is my models.py file:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)

    SUBSCRIPTION_PLANS = (
        ('DEMO', 'Free Trial'),
        ('MONTH','Monthly'),
        ('YEAR','Yearly'),
        ('SIXMONTH','Six month plan'),
    )

    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'profile_pics', blank = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    subscription_plan = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SUBSCRIPTION_PLANS, default = 'DEMO')

    def __str__(self):
         return self.user.username
```

Here is the view.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from UserProfile.forms import UserForm,UserProfileForm
# Create your views here.
def register(request):

    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)


        if user_form.is_valid() and  profile_form .is_valid():

            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                print 'has profile pic'
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']

            profile.save()

            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'UserProfile/registration.html',{'user_form':user_form,
                                                            'profile_form':profile_form,
                                                            'registered':registered})
```

I run `>>python manage.py makemigrations UserProfile` and get:

```
Migrations for 'UserProfile':
  UserProfile/migrations/0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Profile
```

Here is forms.py:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = Profile
        fields = ('subscription_plan', 'first_name', 'profile_pic', 'last_name')
```

I run:

```
>>python manage.py migrate UserProfile
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: UserProfile
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

I try to fill in the form and I still get the error: no such column: profile_pic

```
OperationalError at /user_profile/register
no such column: profile_pic
```

I clearly created the profile_pic column in the model and migrated it. So why does Django think it is not there?

I made an another attempt to recreate the table from scratch:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake UserProfile zero
Operations to perform:
  Unapply all migrations: UserProfile
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Unapplying UserProfile.0001_initial... FAKED

python manage.py makemigrations UserProfile
Migrations for 'UserProfile':
  UserProfile/migrations/0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Profile

python manage.py migrate --fake-initial UserProfile
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: UserProfile
Running migrations:
  Applying UserProfile.0001_initial... FAKED
```

Still the same error.
Running `python manage.py sqlmigrate UserProfile 0001_initial`

```
BEGIN;
--
-- Create model Profile
--
CREATE TABLE "UserProfile_profile" ("user_id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id"), "profile_pic" varchar(100) NOT NULL, "first_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL, "last_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL, "subscription_plan" varchar(10) NOT NULL);
COMMIT;
```

What the hell? The 'profile_pic' field is in the SQL! So what's wrong then?

Traceback:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/ilyalapan/Documents/Development/OE Ventures/businessMaps/businessMaps/UserProfile/views.py" in register
  26.             profile.save()

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  796.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  824.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  889.                                       forced_update)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_update
  939.         return filtered._update(values) > 0

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _update
  654.         return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1148.         cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  835.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  337.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /user_profile/register
Exception Value: no such column: profile_pic
```

UPDATE: I've commented out some the fields from the model, but then I would get the same error with a different field. So if it's not 'profile_pic', it's subscription plan. Some more info - here's forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from UserProfile.models import Profile

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    #TODO: Haven't figured out why this is needed yet. Will check docs
    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = Profile
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name' ,'profile_pic', 'subscription_plan')
```

I will try deleting the Django app and starting again from scratch.

Comment: It doesn't look like the migration actually ran. Are you sure the migration file was there when you ran `migrate`?

Comment: @FamousJameous I've deleted '0001_initial.py' and '0001_initial.pyc' and then ran makemigrations and migrate and '0001_initial.py' appeared again. Anything else I can do to make sure migrations do actually run? Do I need to manually edit the database?

Comment: Did the `migrate` output say "No migrations to apply." again? Or did it actually migrate? Maybe also post the output of `showmigrations`. Were there existing migration files applied before you "delete all the files in the apps 'migrations' folder"?

Comment: @FamousJameous I edited the question showing in more detail what's happening with migrations

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253399/how-to-reset-migrations-in-django-1-7

Comment: Can you please provide full stack of the error? Also for the Profile model, do you add a signal to create it when user object created? Something like: `models.signals.post_save.connect(on_user_save, sender=User)`

Comment: I've read somewhere that you can end up querying the tables before models get properly loaded (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383978/no-such-column-error-in-django-models). Is that what is happening here?

Comment: @GagikSukiasyan where should I put the `models.signals.post_save.connect(on_user_save, sender=User)` and why?

Comment: Please refer to doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/